# Create method chain before object exists

Tags: javascript, method-chaining

Let's say I'm using [knex](https://knexjs.org/) to run queries against an SQL database. I chain a few methods to build the query.

For example:

```
const sqlConfig = require('./sql.config');

var knex = require('knex')(sqlConfig);

knex.select("*")
  .from("books")
  .where("author", "=", "José Saramago")
  .then((rows) => {
    console.log(rows);
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log(err);
  })
  .finally(() => {
    knex.destroy();
  })
```

## Now, my question is:

Is there a way to store the method chain before the `knex` object is created and call it later when it is created?

Something like this:

```
const methodChain = <<<
  .select("*"),
  .from("books"),
  .where("author", "=", "José Saramago")
>>>

const sqlConfig = require('./sql.config');

var knex = require('knex')(sqlConfig);

knex
  .methodChain()
  .then((rows) => {
    console.log(rows);
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log(err);
  })
  .finally(function() {
    knex.destroy();
  })
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a function that accepts the initial parameter in the chain:

```js
function methodChain(in) {
  return in.select("*")
           .from("books")
           .where("author", "=", "José Saramago");
}

methodChain(knex)
  .then((rows) => {
    console.log(rows);
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log(err);
  })
  .finally(function() {
    knex.destroy();
  })
```

Comment: This worked by removing those commas inside `methodChain`. I'm sure you copied from my question, my bad. Thanks!

Comment: @EdgarR.Mondragón You’re right, I missed that! Glad it works for you, and I’ve removed the extraneous commas now.

Answer (score 2):

Sure.

```
const methodChain = (x) => x
    .select("*"),
    .from("books"),
    .where("author", "=", "José Saramago");
```

then later

```
methodChain(knex)
  .then((rows) => {
    console.log(rows);
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log(err);
  })
  .finally(function() {
    knex.destroy();
  })
```